# Regular Expressions - Capture string between " and " that ends in 8digits then .xml

Tags: regex, excel, vba

I'm using Excel VBA.

What syntax do I use to find an alphanumeric string that is between double quotes (excluding the quotes) and also ends in eightnumbers followed by .xml?

I think the digits and xml are captured by \d{8}(.xml) but I can't figure out how to capture all the characters leading up to the eight numbers.

Here's one sample string: "flws-20130929.xml"
Here's another: "aegy.ob-20120731.xml"

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you just testing for a match, or pulling this out of a larger string?

Comment: I'm pulling it out of the body of a webpage.  Here's an example: http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1446896/000144689612000023/.  There are a few files with a .xml extension but only one that has eight digits (which is a date) then .xml.  I need the file name to append to the page's path so I can apply other code to search for items in that file.  So for right now it's just the full file name I need

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick version that just uses the LIKE operator and doesn't use the VBScript Regexp object.

Try the following :

```
s = "flws-20130929.xml"

If s Like "*########.xml" Then Msgbox "Yes"
```

You'll see it does return yes.

If you do have double quotes and want to exclude them :

```
s = """flws-20130929.xml"""
If s Like """*########.xml""" Then MsgBox Mid(s, 2, Len(s) - 2)
```

Comment: Thanks for this Julien.  I don't understand how I would apply this to search the body of a webpage so I can't confirm it works in my case. Note that I have limited html experience.  With RegEx I set an object=RE.Execute(IEbrowser,Document.body.innerhtml) having given RE the pattern to search.  Any thoughts on using VBA to search html is appreciated.  I suppose that if I just iterate setting s=various strings then using Like it would work.

Comment: So would you rather I give you a regex pattern?

Comment: if you know what would work, yes.  I didn't bother to go into detail about searching a webpage in my original post bec I thought it irrelevant.  Sry about that.  If I have an RE Pattern I can plug it into my existing routine to test.  Thanks

Comment: Actually you are very close up there. You want to capture a pattern that starts with a double quote, has a bunch of stuff, apparently a "-" (maybe that's not always the case?) and then eight number. You need to double the double quote, you can probably use * for the "bunch" of stuff and [0-9]{8} or \d{8} is fine. Give it a try and I'll help if you need.

Comment: I gotta run, so I posted the solution below if you need it. I meant it like a little tutorial, and posted what you should actually use when playing with submatches below.

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look.  Been playing with it again.  I am able to capture a single character before \d{8}.xml but not a string of indefinite length that starts after " and ends with \d{8}.xml.  That was what drove my original post. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With VBScript Regex 55

```
Sub GetLink()

Dim RegEx As Object
Set RegEx = New RegExp

Dim MatchCol As MatchCollection

With RegEx
    .Pattern = """([a-zA-Z.-]*[0-9]{8}.xml)"""
    .Global = True ' This parameter is very important or you will only get the first match within the tested string.
End With


' You would be getting that from the webpage, here I created a dummy
s = "<a href=""flws-20130929.xml""></a><p>A paragraph here with another link><a href=""flws-20120717.xml""></a></p>"
Debug.Print s ' (need the Immediate Window to see what it gives, CTRL + G)

Debug.Print RegEx.Test(s)

' Store the results in a collection of matches
Set MatchCol = RegEx.Execute(s)


If MatchCol.Count = 0 Then

    Debug.Print "No Match found"

Else

    For Each Match In MatchCol

        Debug.Print "source >>", Match.Value

        ' Showing you the submatches here. This is within the pattern, what is between parenthesis. Here you only have one anyway...
        For j = 0 To Match.SubMatches.Count - 1

            Debug.Print "[$" & j + 1 & "]", Match.SubMatches(j)

        Next j

    Next Match

End If


End Sub
```

In your case you'll want to do

```
For Each Match In MatchCol
    Debug.print Match.SubMatches(0)
Next Match
```

Comment: The .pattern = """([a-zA-Z]*-[0-9]{8}.xml)""" does not find a match for me.  .pattern = "([a-zA-Z]*-[0-9]{8}.xml)" does work; however it only works on strings of this form "flws-20130929.xml" but not on strings of this form "aegy.ob-20120731.xml".  I'll post the code I'm using to test.

Comment: (?<=")[a-zA-Z0-9.-]*\d{8}.xml(?=") seems to work or at least I've not found a scenario where it fails or provides the wrong result.

Comment: Nice, good job!
I didn't see you could have "." in the indefinite string leading up to the numbers, sorry :)

Comment: Thanks JM.  This search seems to work however it isn't 100% assured to capture just the string I want because it doesn't start at the " and take the characters after that.  I'm relying on the characters after " to be only alphanumerics, '.' and '-' but if you can suggest a search patter that is more iron clad that starts with the " I would appreciate it.  Note I'm in Excel VBA so lookbehinds don't work.

Comment: If they are all within <a href="XXXXX"> you could just extract what's after "<a href=" and ends with '.xml">' or something like that?

Comment: There are quite a few strings within <a href="XXXXX"> so the problem is to identify the one I need.  That one ends in 8 digits and .xml so once that is found the easiest is to look back until a " is found and take all the characters after it up to the 8 digits.  I don't know how to accomplish this with regex.  Is there a way to look backwards from the end of the file?  That way I could use lookahead and combine the results.

Comment: I don't really have time to explore this, but I just thought of something that could be a good idea/workaround. You could use the VBA "Split" fonction with double quotes as the delimiter. Store it in a Variant (which will be an array), loop on each element and check whether it matches what you want at that point. You'll be working with much shorter strings and it will be easier to debug. If s Like "*########.xml" is probably enough in that case